# Is it possible for Hibernate to use a class with no default c'tor as a component or composite-element?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to use some legacy classes in Hibernate. One of the classes doesn't have a default constructor so I get a "org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: .." error. I do not need to persist this class directly. Here is the mapping:

```
<class name="test.geo.support.Observation" table="observation">
        <id access="property" column="obs_msg" name="EncodedObMsg" type="string"/>
                <property name="ReportTime" column="report_time" type="long" />
                <many-to-one name="Station" column="station_id" class="test.geo.Station"/>
    </class>
    <class name="test.geo.Station" table="station">
        <id access="property" column="station_id" name="UniqueId" type="string" />
                <component name="Point" class="test.geo.geometry.PointGeometry">
                    <property name="latitude" type="double" access="field" column="lat" />
                    <property name="longitude" type="double" access="field" column="lon" />
                </component>
    </class>
```

I need to persist the 'Observation' and 'Station', and want to reference the 'PointGeometry' class to persist the Station.Point. Is there any way to pull this off with 'PointGeometry' not having a default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need a no argument constructor.  Hibernate needs a way to create objects.

You might be able to create a subclass of this class, and give the subclass the no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You will always need a no argument constructor. If I really don't like no arg constructor to be called by my code, I make it `protected`.

Comment: the no arg constructor can at most be package private

Comment: @hvgotcodes `protected` definitelly works as it's all over my code. But I take it back about `private`. Answer edited.

Comment: yes protected will work as it is less restrictive than package private.  Note "package private" is one term.  I did not say private.

Comment: I have made the no-args constructor private and Hibernate still works

Answer (score 0):

No. That is a JPA requirement. In Hibernate you can implement an Interceptor that populates the object using as desired. See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433238/2108278
- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html