# Hibernate Envers and "Javassist Enhancement failed" Exception

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are using Hibernate Envers and have the following situation:

A class `BusinessObjectType` and a class `Identity` with a reference to `BusinessObjectType`:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "ID_IDENTITY" )
@Audited
public class Identity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "BO_TYPE_ID" )
    @IndexColumn( name = "INDEX_BO_BO_TYPE" )
    private BusinessObjectType businessObjectType;

    […]

}
```

We then query for all the version of Identity with:

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(
    Identity.class,
    false,
    true );
auditQuery.add( AuditEntity.id().eq( dbid ) );

@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
List< Object[]> history = (List< Object[]>) auditQuery.getResultList();
```

If the stored identity does not have a `BusinessObjectType` (i.e., `businessObjectType` is and was null) everything works like a charm.

If the identity had a `businessObjectType != null` we get a "Javassist Enhancement failed" Exception:

```
Javassist Enhancement failed: ch.ethz.id.wai.baseclasses.BusinessObjectType
```

The error seems to be related to Envers trying to instantiate a BusinessObjectType but I don't really see what the problem could be (Hibernate has no problems with both objects if we don't use an AuditQuery).

The cause of the exception is

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: ch.ethz.id.wai.baseclasses.BusinessObjectType_$$_javassist_49
```

with no stack trace.

Any hint on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens inside the following class [JavassistLazyInitializer](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.1.ga/hibernate-3.2.1.ga-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/proxy/pojo/javassist/JavassistLazyInitializer.java?format=ok)  A Javassist-based lazy initializer proxy.

Without having a look at full source it is difficult to comment but you can try following options.

- Turn off Lazy loading for @ManyToOne relationship [**This is a design decision so watch out if it doesn't fit in overall solution**]
- Provide a default public constructor for your entity which is causing problem[This is easier]
- turn off reflection optimisation if not really required by setting up     `hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer` property to false

Let us know if this helps

Comment: Fetching is the default: SELECT. The constructor was not public. Thanks. I still have to understand why Envers wants to instantiate more than plain Hibernate.

Comment: why must the default constructor be `public`? I see a potentially conflicting answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor#comment9688725_2971717)

Answer (score 1):

To get a more information about the exception, use the debugging facilities of your IDE to set an exception breakpoint for `java.lang.InstantiationException` to halt execution when the underlying exception occurs. This should show you the full stack trace, and allow you to inspect all variables on the stack.

If I had to guess, my first suspicion would be that since the association to 
`BusinessObjectType` is not mapped lazy, plain hibernate doesn't ever try to create a proxy for the class. Envers in contrast appears to do. A proxy is a subclass generated at runtime overriding all public methods. Therefore, neither the class nor any public methods (beside those inherited from `Object`) may be declared `final`, and a default constructor must be accessible to the subclass.

Comment: I have the same suspect: Envers tries to fetch more (otherwise I would not have the error). One problem is: why? How can I avoid it? On the other hand BusinessObjectType has a default public constructor and no final fields. With plain Envers it can be fetched without any problems.

Comment: ... and no final methods either? I don't know enough about the internals of Envers to guess further. That's why I would start debugging to get more information.

Comment: Actually I didn't notice that during the last changes to test I re-made the constructor private. By the way: with a public constructor finals methods seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: I awarded the bounty to user3965072 since he was first ... I didn't have the possibility to test right after his answer (week-end :-)