# Configuration error between Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

My application is built with Spring 2.5, Hibernate 3 and JSF 1.2

Upon starting tomcat this error showed up:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource
[application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is :org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
```

My application-context.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pfe"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>DAO.Action</value>
                <value>DAO.Etat</value>
                <value>DAO.EtatSuivi</value>
                <value>DAO.Reclamation</value>
                <value>DAO.TypeAction</value>
                <value>DAO.Utilisateur</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props><prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop></props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="DAO"></context:component-scan> 
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>GestionReclamations</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### jars:

spring
antlr-2.7.6
asm-3.2
cglib-2.2
ejb3-persitence
hibernate-annotations
hibernate-commons-annotation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891154/unable-to-instantiate-default-tuplizer-org-hibernate-tuple-entity-pojoentitytup may help.  In that case, it was a missing setter property, and check your entire stack trace

Comment: "Swing"? Are you sure?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels seems to be a Typo, should be Spring

Comment: Is spring-orm jar available? What other spring jar files is available? Or is the spring jar containing complete bundle?

Comment: @Algorithmist: or "Sping". ;)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace... Judging from the short list of jars you are missing a hibernate jar (you only have the annotations and EJB 3 api).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a hibernate jar. Sure everything is in its place? Please post the entire stacktrace.

Could also be this one:

[org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930495/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-unable-to-instantiate-default-tuplizer-org-hi)