# Does Spring Data JPA's @PersistenceConstructor annotation work in combination with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want Hibernate to use another constructor than an empty constructor since I have some logic that should be executed on object creation but depends on the object properties. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099127/java-entity-why-do-i-need-an-empty-constructor) that `@PersistenceConstructor` solves this.

I created this example entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    public final Long id;

    public final int width;

    public final int height;

    @Transient
    private final double area;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public TestEntity(Long id, int width, int height)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.area = width * height;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return this.area;
    }

    public interface TestEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long>
    {
    }
}
```

However, when I try to retrieve an instance from the database, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the `@PersistenceConstructor` annotation not work in this context?

Comment: Since `@PersistenceConstructor` is apparently a "Spring Data JPA" annotation then it safe to assume that Hibernate will NOT "support" it, since it supports the JPA API

Comment: Ok so I guess the question should be 'Does Spring Data JPA's @PersistenceConstructor annotation work in combination with hibernate?'

Comment: As far as I can tell, PersistenceConstructor has no effect with JPA/Hibernate persistence (because JPA/Hibernate persistence always want a default constructor, and use setter to set properties).
PersistenceConstructor is only useful with noSql Spring-data persistence flavor : MongoDb, etc.

Comment: Then it makes sense why @PersistenceConstructor exists, maybe Hibernate makes it work in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data `@PersistenceConstructor` does not work with JPA. It works only in modules that do not use the object mapping of the underlying data store.