# How to properly publish DDD domain events with spring?

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

I am trying to implement domain driven design in my project.
Here is my base `Aggregate` class:

```
public abstract class UUIDAggregate {
    private final DomainEventPublisher domainEventPublisher;

    protected void publish(DomainEvent domainEvent) {
        domainEventPublisher.publish(domainEvent);
    }
}
```

Let's say we have `UserAccount` aggregate:

```
public class UserAccount extends UUIDAggregate {
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public void update() {
        publish(new DomainEventImpl());
    }
}
```

Here is my `DomainEventPublisher`:

```
public interface DomainEventPublisher {
   void publish(DomainEvent event);
}
```

Here is `DomainEventPublisherImpl`:

```
@Component
public class DomainEventPublisherImpl implements DomainEventPublisher{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void publish(DomainEvent event){
        publisher.publishEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Now, this seems like a good idea, the domain is separated from implementation but this does not work. `DomainEventPublisher` cannot be `Autowired` because `UUIDAggregate` is not a `@Component` or `@Bean` . One solution would be to create `DomainService` and publish event there but that seems like leaking of domain to domain service and if I go that way, I am going to anemic model. Also what I can do is to pass `DomainEventPublisher` as a parameter to every aggregate but that also does not seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to have a factory for domain objects:

```
@Component
class UserAccountFactoryImpl implements UserAccountFactory {
    @Autowired
    private DomainEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public UserAccount newUserAccount(String email, String username, ...) {
        return new UserAccount(email, username, ..., publisher);
    }
}
```

Then your code creating a domain object is "publisher-free":

```
UserAccount userAccount = factory.newUserAccount("john@example.com", ...);
```

Or you might slightly change the design of the event-publishing:

```
public abstract class UUIDAggregate {
    private final List<DomainEvent> domainEvents = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void publish(DomainEvent domainEvent) {
        domainEvents.add(domainEvent);
    }
    public List<DomainEvent> domainEvents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(domainEvents);
    }
}

@Component
class UserAccountServiceImpl implements UserAccountService {
    @Autowired
    private DomainEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void updateUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount) {
        userAccount.update();

        userAccount.domainEvents().forEach(publisher::publishEvent);
    }
}
```

This is different from your proposal: the service *publishes* the events, but *doesn't create* then - the logic stays in the domain object.

Further, you can change your publisher to minimize the boiler-plate code:

```
public interface DomainEventPublisher {
   void publish(UUIDAggregate aggregate);
}
```

Comment: I like your first idea, actually, that was what I was thinking also. The only "problem" was that my builder class was static(similar thing like Lombok builder) so I didn't want to create instances of UserAccout builder(although when I think now, I couldn't find any real reason why that would be bad). But I think that is completely "DDD way" of thinking and I will go that way. About second idea, also I had it in mind but if we always publish an event when updating user account, updating and publishing shouldn't be separated. There is a big chance that someone will forget to publish an event.

Comment: Your second implementation proposal is DEFINETLY the way to do it. Even Spring's AbstractAggregateRoot (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractAggregateRoot.html) works in this way. basically every command could trigger many events (but it's dangerous without event sourcing or sagas) so ther should be published after the aggregate mutation is committed

Answer (score 1):

Vaughn Vernon in his book IDDD just uses singleton like this:

```
DomainEventPublisher.instance().register(...);

DomainEventPublisher.instance().publish(...);
```

I know this approach doesn't use spring injection but it's much simplier than passing publisher to every aggregate and not that hard to test.