# @OneToOne mapping isnt working in my Java Spring project

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

So I am tidying up my small Spring project and I noticed for some reason the @OneToOne annotation is not doing its job for me which in turn causes issues in another model.

github link : https://github.com/eamonmckelvey/sports-app

Basically, I have a User model class, a team model class and a player model class.
I want only one user to be able to create one team, and one team to have many players.
However, I am able to add as many teams to my user as I want which is wrong.

All the answers provided require me to add a no arg constructor and a constructor for my users class, but when I do this I get an error in my registration from class.

Please help.

## 1. User Model

```
 @Entity
 @Data
 @NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class User implements UserDetails {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
    private Team team;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    //private final String fullname;




    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
       }
   }
```

## 2. Team Model

```
@Data
@Entity
 @Table(name="User_Team")

public class Team implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)

private User user;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

//@NotBlank(message="Team Name is required")
private  String teamName;

//@NotBlank(message="Location is required")
private  String location;

//@NotBlank(message="Nickname required")
private String nickName;

private String yearEstablished;

public Sport sport;

private Divison divison;
```

## 3. Team Controller

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("Team")

public class TeamController {

private TeamRepository teamRepository;

public TeamController(TeamRepository teamRepository) {
    this.teamRepository = teamRepository;
}

 @Autowired
 TeamRepository service;

 @GetMapping("/team")
 public String displayTeam(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("team", service.findAll());

    return "/team";
   }

    @GetMapping("/addTeam")
    public String showSignUpForm(User user) {
    return "addTeam";
   }

    @PostMapping("/addTeam")
    public String processOrder(@Valid Team team, BindingResult result, SessionStatus 
    sessionStatus,
                           @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addTeam";
    }

    team.setUser(user);
    service.save(team);
    model.addAttribute("team", service.findAll());
    return "team";
}
```

## 4. Registeration Form

```
@Data
public class RegistrationForm {
private String username;
private String password;
//private String fullname;


 public User toUser(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    return new User(
            username, passwordEncoder.encode(password));
}
}
```

## 5. Registration Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {

private UserRepository userRepo;
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public RegistrationController( UserRepository userRepo, 
 PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

 @GetMapping
 public String registerForm(){
    return "registration";
 }
  @PostMapping
 public String processRegistration(RegistrationForm form){
    userRepo.save(form.toUser(passwordEncoder));
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

## 6. user details class

```
@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements 
UserDetailsService {

private UserRepository userRepo;
@Autowired
public UserRepositoryUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    if (user != null) {
        return user;
    }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            "User '" + username + "' not found");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey so i found a fix here for my code.

## 1. Team Controller

```
      @GetMapping("/addTeam")
      public String showSignUpForm(SessionStatus sessionStatus,
                             @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model) 
 {
      //if the user has already the team we should not let them add another 
      // one
      //this is due to having one to one relationship
     long userHasTeamCount = service.countAllByUser(user);
     if (userHasTeamCount > 0) {

        return "redirect:team";

     }

    return "addTeam";
  }
```

## 2. Team model

```
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private User user;
```

## 3. User Model

Removed the OneToOne here as its not needed

## 4. Team repo

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {
Team findAllById(Long id);


long countAllByUser(final User user);
```

}

Comment: Can a Team have many Users?  If so, I think your Team.user field should be a collection (named users) annotated with @OneToMany since **One** Team can have **Many** Users

Also, I think your TeamRepository.findAllById would be better named findById

Answer (score 5):

1) One user can have one team. That means `OneToOne` relation between user and team. You need not to annotate both user and team with @OneToOne.Remove @OneToOne annotation from team model. 
Changes required are:

User model:

```
@Entity
class User{ 

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

//other fields
}
```

Team Model:

```
@Entity
class Team{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private  String teamName;
    //other field
    }
```

2) For one team to have many players requires `@OneToMany`

Comment: Still doesnt work. It gives a "Data too long for column "user" ". Also in my team model i need to have a field as such private User user because in the team controller i have a @PostMapping method for adding the team. If i remove private User user this method throws an error at team.setUser(user)

Comment: also you say user and model both need to be annotated but then you say remove the annotation from team model, how does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

So, I copied your code and did some changes. After the following changes your code works fine.

1) Drop final keyword from below fields in user class(initalizing them doesn't seems to be a great idea).

```
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
```

2) User and Team should not have same serialization version.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

3) After doing above corrections. Your code will give you the actual error "nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException"

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)

..............
..........

    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
```

To avoid it do the following changes in your model :

**Put @Table(name="users") in user model.**

Following are the models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Team team;

    public User() {
    }

}
```

Team Model

```
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {


    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
// or you can use
//    @OneToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    private  String teamName;

    public Team() {
    }

}
```

Follow the above code. It works fine for me. Test Controller to check:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        User user = userRepository.findById(2l);
        Team team = user.getTeam();
        return new ResponseEntity(team, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Hey thanks , your solution makes sense but when i run it i get this error : Error:(18, 5) java: constructor User() is already defined in class sportsapp.sportsapp.User

Comment: why do i need an empty Public User() contructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099127/java-entity-why-do-i-need-an-empty-constructor

Comment: your solution removes the RequiredArgsConstructor and NoArgeConstructor but the project i am creating requires them for my registration model. Is there a workaround?

Comment: solution doesnt work. Have you any more suggestions? thnx

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `@JoinColumn` on the child side is missing. It's not even on the parent side. In the `User` entity you declare `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")`, but it is not mapped in the child class.
2. `FetchType.LAZY` does not give you much in terms of performance in one-to-one, since hibernate needs to check the database for existence of an object to know whether return a proxy or `null`.
3. You're saving a child entity in your `TeamController`: `service.save(team);`, but there is no cascading from `Team` to `User`.

Try the following mapping:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Team team;

    // other fields
}

public class Team implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // other fields
}
```

And keeping both sides synchronized. Instead of:

```
team.setUser(user);
service.save(team);
```

Try the following code in your `TeamController` (you will have to autowire `UserRepository`):

```
team = service.save(team);
team.setUser(user);
user.setTeam(team);
userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: I get  this erros : Error:(16, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method value()
  location: @interface javax.persistence.JoinColumn and it tells me to use @JoinColumn(columnDefintion ="user_id"), if i  use that and run i get this error : detached entity passed to persist

Comment: @EamonMac sorry, you need to add `name = ` in the `@JoinColumn`. I forgot about that

Comment: ok, done that and when i save my "team" i get this error :detached entity passed to persist. Not sure what that means!

Comment: @EamonMac could you add `user.setTeam(team);` before `service.save(team);` and then try again?

Comment: when i do that i get my original issue..foreign key works but multiple instances are saved.:(

Comment: @EamonMac are you sure, that neither `team` nor `user` are `null`?

Comment: sorry, i wasnt logged in and thats why it gave that error. but anyway now my original issue is back, foreign key works but allows more than one instance.

Comment: @EamonMac I have edited the answer with additional synchronization, can you try it now?

Comment: still allows more than one instance in the table for teams!

Comment: @EamonMac can you write a junit test for this problem and push it to github? I'll pull it then and try to resolve it locally

Comment: to be honest not sure how i would do that..basically brand new to spring and havent done much testing apart from simple assertions :(

Comment: like a test case that adds a new user and verifies it match's the expected values? or one where you get an existing team and verify it was added correctly, thank you @Androncious

Comment: The test, that describes your situation, so that I fix the code to make the test pass (TDD). The test should invoke the same methods as frontend does and in the database only one team with `user_id` is expected

Comment: How do i access my repository in a test class? annotations such as autowired are not permitted. And for writing a test case, its always going to pass because i am able to add as many rows as i want.