# Hibernate-Could not parse mapping document from input stream

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I have builded a java application(maven) to run on server.I use Eclipse Luna, Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.When I run it, I have an error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF//applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3762)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3751)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3739)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.hibernate.data.Person
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2835)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3759)
... 31 more
```

Searching similar questions on web,I thought it occurs due to lack of some hibernate dependencies and added them.But it didn't work.Now, I am out of ideas!

My project is here: https://github.com/fsel/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Eclipse-Integration/tree/master/Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.hibernate.data.Person
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2835)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3759)
```

above exception convey that there are duplicate mapping for com.hibernate.data.Person

your hinernate.cfg.xml has below code

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PERSONDB</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">fulden</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">secret_pass</property>
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Specify session context -->
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<!-- Show SQL -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!-- Referring Mapping File -->
<mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and your applicationContext.xml has below code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
<!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.service"></context:component-scan>
<!-- Create Data Source bean -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PERSONDB" />
<property name="username" value="fulden" />
<property name="password" value="secret_pass" />
</bean>
<!-- Define SessionFactory bean -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>domain-classes.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="configLocation">
<value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
</bean>
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

if you closely observe both files  you are duplicating hibernate mapping resource

In hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml"/>
```

In a applicatinContext.xml

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
    <value>domain-classes.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
```

> solution: 
>         removing mappingResources property  from applicatinContext.xml file should resolve you problem

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `Person Class` is loaded twice.

In `Spring configuration - applicationContext.xml` file you have :

```
<property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>domain-classes.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

Also in `hibernate configuration - hibernate.cfg.xml` file you are loading it once again:

```
<mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml"/>
```

To fix the issue, just remove one of the above entries, either from Spring configuration file or Hibernate configuration file.

Comment: I have just edited both files, it now works.Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a constructor without arguments in Person.

> Hibernate, and code in general that creates objects via reflection use
>   Class.newInstance() to create a new instance of your classes. This
>   method requires a **public no-arg constructor** to be able to
>   instantiate the object. For most use cases, providing a no-arg
>   constructor is not a problem.

Source :
[Why does Hibernate require no argument constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor)

Comment: I added a no argument constructor to the Person class.But it still gives the same error:/

Comment: @oddly You had had it there already before. Java creates a default constructor if there is none.