# No default constructor for entity: : com.devglan.model.Product

Tags: hibernate

In the product class i have created parameterized construction while fetching data from data base i was getting error " No default constructor for entity ",

whenever we created parameterized construction in entity class. is default  constructor mandatory to create?

Comment: yes the Default constructor is mandatory

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate require a no-arguments constructor to create a new instance of your entity using reflection.
many framework work like this, check this good question about it 
[Why does Hibernate require no argument constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor)

From Hibernate doc.:

> All persistent classes must have a default constructor (which can be
>   non-public) so that Hibernate can instantiate them using
>   Constructor.newInstance(). It is recommended that you have a default
>   constructor with at least package visibility for runtime proxy
>   generation in Hibernate.