# Does Hibernate really need no-args constructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

It is well known that Hibernate needs no-args constructor, but I tried to delete it and surprisingly everything work fine.
I use Spring-Boot in my project and while I run the program I got this message:

```
2020-09-04 00:13:24.749  INFO 12825 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.jb.couponSystem.data.entity.Coupon (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
```

What is that Interceptor that instantiated my class? and why in other projects if I don't have no args constructor Hibernate throws an exception (as expected)?

This is the class, I use Lombok @Data for reducing boilerplate code:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Coupon {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private long id;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private  String title;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private LocalDate startDate;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private LocalDate endDate;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Category category;
private int amount;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private String description;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(nullable = false)
private double price;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private String imageURL;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Company company;
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "customer_coupon",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames
                = {"customer_id", "coupon_id"}))
private List<Customer> customers;


public Coupon(String title, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate,
              Category category, int amount, String description, double price, String imageURL) {
    this.title = title;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.category = category;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}


public boolean isOutOfStock() {
    return amount <= 0;
}
```

}

Update: To make clear, this behavior for sure is not related to lombok @Data . Even when I delete that annotation and add getters and setters it still works with the same Hibernate message.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433238/14218910) is some interesting answer concerning this issue, but it assumes that You have to implement yourself Interceptor- what I didn't do. Maybe Spring-Boot itself passes an already implemented interceptor while creating the session factory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Hibernate require no argument constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor). Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433238/4880379 ?

Comment: @kasptom That is interesting answer but it assumes that You implemented instantiate() method of Interceptor. In my case I didn't do that. Does Spring-Boot passes an already implemented interceptor while creating the  Session factory ?