# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null [Spring Boot, Hibernate]

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes **User.java** and **Address.java** and there is a **one-to-one bi-directional mapping** between them.

But when I try to get the address using the **User** class I get an **"java.lang.StackOverflowError: null"** exception.

The same thing happens when I try to get the **User** from the **Address** class.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String imageUrl;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    private Address address;
```

**Address.java**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;
    
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String pincode;
```

**MainController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @Autowired
    private AddressDao addressDao;
    
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("name");
        user.setEmail("email");
        user.setPhone("phone");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setImageUrl("imageUrl");
        
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCountry("country");
        address.setState("state");
        address.setCity("city");
        address.setStreet("street");
        address.setPincode("123456");
        
        user.setAddress(address);
        userDao.save(user);
        
        return "working";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/fetch")
    @ResponseBody
    public String fetch() {
        User user = userDao.getById((long) 1);
        System.out.println(user.getAddress());
        
        return "working";
    }
}
```

I am using the **test()** function to put data in the database and it is working fine.
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwHZr.png)

But when I call the **fetch()** function I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer.invoke(BasicLazyInitializer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at
```

Updated MainController.java

```
package com.demo.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.demo.dao.AddressDao;
import com.demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.demo.entity.Address;
import com.demo.entity.User;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @Autowired
    private AddressDao addressDao;
    
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("name");
        user.setEmail("email");
        user.setPhone("phone");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setImageUrl("imageUrl");
        
        userDao.save(user);
        
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCountry("country");
        address.setState("state");
        address.setCity("city");
        address.setStreet("street");
        address.setPincode("123456");
        
        addressDao.save(address);
        
        user.setAddress(address);
        userDao.save(user);
        
        return "working";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/fetch")
    @ResponseBody
    public String fetch() {
        Optional<User> op = userDao.findById((long) 1);
        User user = op.get();
        
        // working
        System.out.println(user.getName() + " " + user.getEmail() + " " + user.getPhone());
    
        // java.lang.StackOverflowError:null
        System.out.println(user.getAddress());
        
        return "working";
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you call internally is going in loop -> User calling Address. Address again calling User & so on.

Comment: Can you show me your both `dao` or `repository`

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace?

Comment: UserDao `public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
 
}
`AddressDao `public interface AddressDao extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>{
}` @Faeemazaz

Comment: Where is `getById()` mehod?

Comment: @Faeemazaz it is already implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: you aren't actually saving anything anywhere, but it's easy to fix. Here's my code and my explanation:

MainController.java:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    public MainController(UserRepository userRepository, AddressRepository addressRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("name");
        user.setEmail("email");
        user.setPhone("phone");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setImageUrl("imageUrl");

        user = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("saved user");

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCountry("country");
        address.setState("state");
        address.setCity("city");
        address.setStreet("street");
        address.setPincode("123456");

        address = addressRepository.save(address);
        System.out.println("saved address");

        user.setAddress(address);
        userRepository.save(user);

        System.out.println("set user's address");
        return "working";
    }

    @GetMapping("/fetch")
    public String fetch() {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById((long) 1);
        if(optionalUser.isPresent()){
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            System.out.println(user.getAddress());

            boolean addressExists = addressRepository.existsById((long) 1);
            System.out.println(addressExists);
            System.out.println(user.getAddress().getCountry());

            return "working";
        }

        System.out.println("Error: user with id 1 not found!");
        return "failing";
    }
}
```

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String imageUrl;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Address.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;

    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String pincode;
    
    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

AddressRepository.java:

```
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {

}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

UserDAO.java:

```
public class UserDAO {
    private final String name;
    private final String email;
    private final String phone;
    private final String imageUrl;
    
    public UserDAO(User user) {
        name = user.getName();
        email = user.getEmail();
        phone = user.getPhone();
        imageUrl = user.getImageUrl();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

A DAO has no connection to the database, it's intent is what the acronym stands for, simply to transfer data, and that's it. When you make a repository, you can stick your objects there by saving them in the repository. Notice that by extending the `CrudRepository` with correct generics, you don't even need to implement the methods yourself. The `save` method actually saves the POJO, and returns the saved version, which is why I did `user = userRepository.save(user)`, which may seem counterintuitive at first, but it simply helps ensure that everything is as you expect. If you then want to send the `UserDAO` object as a response, you can create it using the `user` object that is returned from the database, maybe something like:

```
UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(userRepository.save(user));
```

Please take notice of what is happening inside the `test` method in `MainController`. First, we create the POJO `User` object and set its fields. Then we have to save it to the repository, it is only persisted after you call `save` method of the repository. Please note that the `user` object is saved again once it is updated with the `address`.

This is a very crude way to do things, it is best to create a service layer and do this there with the `@Transactional` annotation, which would mean that everything is rolled back in case something goes wrong inside a method annotated as `@Transactional`.

Also, using `CascadeType.ALL` may be not what you want, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027444/17105581).

Inside `fetch` method, I ensure that the `user` indeed exists, which is not guaranteed. To avoid 500 errors, it's important to have a fallback mechanism for when something doesn't work.

As a final side note, you shouldn't be storing raw passwords like that, you should at least use hashing with salt and pepper, or use one of the many available libraries for implementing such functionality (although it can be quite fun getting down and dirty with the code itself). You should also consider how much information you are revealing when something does go wrong, as you don't want to give away too much information which could be used to deanonimise a specific user, or even learn more about your code and the system architecture.

Comment: thanks for replying I made some changes you suggested but I am still getting the same error as before. I have getters and setters in the User and Address class itself and I am using UserDao and AddressDao as UserRepository and AddressRepository and data is getting saved in the database as well. I can fetch all the attributes except the Address attribute.

Comment: Remove `CascadeType.ALL` from Address.java `User` field

Comment: In Address.java, it should look like `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;`

Comment: Did that as well

Comment: In User.java, it should be `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;`

Comment: Make sure the reference column is present

Comment: @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
 private User user;

Comment: @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Address address;

Comment: When I run the application, and I get output `com.example.demo.Address@1c6525c5` for the address (which shows that the object is present) and I get `country` output in the console when I print `address.getCountry()`

Comment: Get rid of autowired dao my friend. Autowired is useful when you have a `Bean` and you want to include it. That's not what DAO are for :)

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: program is running fine when there is a one-to-one unidirectional mapping from user to address I am getting problem when trying to implement bidirectional mapping

Comment: My friend, if you try making a new project, and just copy everything I have provided, I think you will see what's going on very quickly! Give it a spin and tell me how it goes, I'm more than happy to provide more detail if necessary :)

Comment: Why do you want a bidirectional mapping?

Comment: ok thank you I will get back to you after creating a new project

Comment: so that I can get a list of users residing in the same address

Comment: I tried your solution it is working. The only difference I found in my code and yours was that I had put the parameterized constructors and toString methods in user class and address class, so I removed those methods and the program is working fine now. Are we not supposed to put them in our classes when creating ORM ?

Comment: I think you are correct, hibernate apparently [requires a no-arg constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2971717/17105581).