# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory....' Although I defined you correctly my db with my entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-starter-security

i dont understood why i get this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: ParkingCRMSystemWithThymeleafAndSpringDataJpa.CRMParkingSystem.Security.User
```

i am trying to add security on exit spring boor crm project.
maybe the names well be conused, so i try to be clear,

i have project of crm, and on the project i created new package of security(there is not connection between them, i only practice security on spring boot),
it his pachage i have entity of User, the db name on my sql is parking.login
the db on the crm project work fine, but in the security failed, maybe i miss something?

```
    package ParkingCRMSystemWithThymeleafAndSpringDataJpa.CRMParkingSystem.Security;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

   @Entity
@Table(name = "login")
public class User {
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnable(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    
}
```

pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Parking-CRM-System-With-Thymeleaf-And-SpringDataJpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRM-Parking-System</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CRM-Parking-System</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if its matter, my gol is like in this tuturial:
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-security-authentication-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `@Id`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
```

You are required to manually write a no-arg constructor for that entity since Hibernate requires that from you.

```
public User() {
}
```

[reference for no-arg constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor)