# Read Data from MariaDB with SpringBoot JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entity

I want to try out a simple Spring Boot Hibernate example.

I have this Database:

```
create or replace table treasurelog.categories
(
    id   bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(20) null
);
```

And i want to use JPA Hibernate to get the data from it.
The acces is via a CategoriesController and a JPARepository.

As shown above, my Table Categories in the DB, only having the ID as PK and a name.

Then I wrote this controller:

```
@RestController
public class FindingController {
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public FindingController(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/categories")
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

with this Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

    @Query("select Category as category from Category ")
    public List<Category> findAll();
}
```

and this Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 20)
    private String name;

}
```

But I always get this error while trying a GET:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.DiscriminatorType.getJdbcJavaType()" because "this.discriminatorType" is null
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.EntityTypeLiteral.createSqlSelection(EntityTypeLiteral.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.EntityTypeLiteral.createDomainResult(EntityTypeLiteral.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitSelection$23(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2287) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4966) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelection(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2282) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2200) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2044) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec.accept(SqmQuerySpec.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.spi.BaseSemanticQueryWalker.visitQueryPart(BaseSemanticQueryWalker.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQueryPart(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1902) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1587) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement.accept(SqmSelectStatement.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.translate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:770) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
```

In the tutorials I saw was nothing written about a DescriminatorType.

I hope somebody can give me some Information.

Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer with some references that help you to understand more about how to work with these technologies that you have as tag, just check my answer and give me feedback if it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in repository interface change `<Category, Integer>` to `<Category, Long>` because primary key of entity class is `Long`

Second one change field declaration in controller from

```
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository
```

to

```
private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository
```

if you want to have [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html)

And last one in entity class `Category` also declare an default constructor without any arguments and one with all arguments, it is going to help you. A good answer about it you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor)

P.S. The query in repository should be so:

```
@Query("SELECT cat FROM Category cat ")
public List<Category> findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1. Change the “JpaRepository<Category, Integer>“ to “JpaRepository<Category, Long>” as the second item denotes your primary key or entity id type
2. Try changing your jpql to “select category from Category category”